# c program function not working properly

Tags: c, function, file

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void createIndexFile(char[]);

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char fname[40];
    int option;

    printf("\nEnter the filename to open: ");
    scanf("%s",fname);

    fp=fopen(fname,"r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nCannot open the file\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n%s",fname);
        createIndexFile(fname);
    }

    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n*****MENU*****\n");
        printf("\n1.Display ......\n2.Insert new data\n3.Find data\n4.Display data\n5.Exit\n");
        printf("\nChoose an operation: ");
        scanf("%d",&option);

        switch(option)
        {
            case 1: break;

            case 2: break;

            case 3: break;

            case 4: break;

            case 5: return 0;

            default: printf("\nInvalid selection\n");
         }
    }
}

void createIndexFile(char fname[])
{
    int i=0;
    char tempFile[40];
    char indexFile[40];

    printf("\n%s",fname);

    strcpy(indexFile,"xyz");
    strcpy(tempFile,fname);

    while(tempFile[i]!='.')
    {
        if(tempFile[i]=='/')
        tempFile[i]='_';
    }
    strcat(tempFile,".idx");
    strcat(indexFile,tempFile);
    printf("\nIndex File Name: %s",indexFile);
}
```

It is a program where after a filename is entered suppose `/home/abc.txt` and my name is `xyz` then an index file should be created `xyz_home_abc.idx`.

After the filename is entered and if it is present, it should go to else part and function

```
createIndexFile(fname);
```

should be called. But inside the function, nothing is working properly. If we print a character or something, it is printed. But if I try to give another printf it is not working.

Comment: You missed `i++;` inside `while(tempFile[i]!='.')` loop.

Comment: Well, it's time to learn how to use your debugger.

Comment: Thank u so much. I forgot to increment 'i' inside while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected your function

```
void createIndexFile(char fname[])
{
    int i=0;
    char tempFile[40];
    char indexFile[40];
    printf("\n%s",fname);
    strcpy(indexFile,"");
    while(fname[i]!='.')
    {
        if(fname[i]=='/')
         tempFile[i]='_';
        else
         tempFile[i]=fname[i];
      i++;
    }
     tempFile[i]='\0';
    strcat(tempFile,".idx");
    strcat(indexFile,tempFile);
    printf("\nIndex File Name: %s",indexFile);
}
```